# Thumbnail not visible when posting youtube url from facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I post a url of youtube from my application using Facebook SDK then it posts as a link,no thumbnail image lodes.So please suggest me ,what am i missing?

my code is

```
    Request myreq = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(currentSession,

    "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6acRHWnfZAE", new Request.Callback() {

    @Override

    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
//some code  
    }

    });


    myreq.executeAsync();
```